# i cant switch themes with these method can you solve it?

Tags: dart

static switchTheme({required ThemeBase newTheme}) {
VariableUtilities.theme = newTheme;

```
switch (newTheme) {
  case LightTheme():
    ThemeBase theme = const LightTheme();

    return VariableUtilities.prefs
        .setString(LocalCacheKey.applicationThemeMode, theme.toString());

  case DarkTheme():
    ThemeBase theme = const DarkTheme();

    return VariableUtilities.prefs
        .setString(LocalCacheKey.applicationThemeMode, theme.toString());

  default:
    ThemeBase theme = const LightTheme();

    return VariableUtilities.prefs
        .setString(LocalCacheKey.applicationThemeMode, theme.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can change theme like this. it's from flutter skeleton template.
it can change base of platform theme mode too.

### main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Set up the SettingsController, which will glue user settings to multiple
  // Flutter Widgets.
  final settingsController = SettingsController(SettingsService());

  // Load the user's preferred theme while the splash screen is displayed.
  // This prevents a sudden theme change when the app is first displayed.
  await settingsController.loadSettings();

  // Run the app and pass in the SettingsController. The app listens to the
  // SettingsController for changes, then passes it further down to the
  // SettingsView.

  runApp(MyApp(settingsController: settingsController));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
    required this.settingsController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final SettingsController settingsController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    // Glue the SettingsController to the MaterialApp.
    //
    // The AnimatedBuilder Widget listens to the SettingsController for changes.
    // Whenever the user updates their settings, the MaterialApp is rebuilt.
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: settingsController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          restorationScopeId: 'MyApp',
          theme: AppTheme.newLightTheme(),
          darkTheme: AppTheme.newDarkTheme(),
          themeMode: settingsController.themeMode,
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings routeSettings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
              settings: routeSettings,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                switch (routeSettings.name) {
                  case MainScreen.routeName:
                    return MainScreen(settingsController: settingsController);
                  default:
                    return const ChooseLogin();
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### settings_controller.dart

```
/// A class that many Widgets can interact with to read user settings, update
/// user settings, or listen to user settings changes.
///
/// Controllers glue Data Services to Flutter Widgets. The SettingsController
/// uses the SettingsService to store and retrieve user settings.
class SettingsController with ChangeNotifier {
  SettingsController(this._settingsService);

  // Make SettingsService a private variable so it is not used directly.
  final SettingsService _settingsService;

  // Make ThemeMode a private variable so it is not updated directly without
  // also persisting the changes with the SettingsService.
  late ThemeMode _themeMode;

  // Allow Widgets to read the user's preferred ThemeMode.
  ThemeMode get themeMode => _themeMode;

  /// Load the user's settings from the SettingsService. It may load from a
  /// local database or the internet. The controller only knows it can load the
  /// settings from the service.
  Future<void> loadSettings() async {
    _themeMode = await _settingsService.themeMode();

    // Important! Inform listeners a change has occurred.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Update and persist the ThemeMode based on the user's selection.
  Future<void> updateThemeMode(ThemeMode? newThemeMode) async {
    if (newThemeMode == null) return;

    // Do not perform any work if new and old ThemeMode are identical
    if (newThemeMode == _themeMode) return;

    // Otherwise, store the new ThemeMode in memory
    _themeMode = newThemeMode;

    // Important! Inform listeners a change has occurred.
    notifyListeners();

    // Persist the changes to a local database or the internet using the
    // SettingService.
    await _settingsService.updateThemeMode(newThemeMode);
  }
}
```

### settings_services.dart

```
/// A service that stores and retrieves user settings.
///
/// By default, this class does not persist user settings. If you'd like to
/// persist the user settings locally, use the shared_preferences package. If
/// you'd like to store settings on a web server, use the http package.
class SettingsService {
  static const String kPrefKeyThemeMode = 'ThemeMode';

  /// Loads the User's preferred ThemeMode from local or remote storage.
  Future<ThemeMode> themeMode() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String _name = _prefs.getString(kPrefKeyThemeMode) ?? ThemeMode.system.name;
    if (_name == ThemeMode.light.name) {
      return ThemeMode.light;
    } else if (_name == ThemeMode.dark.name) {
      return ThemeMode.dark;
    } else {
      return ThemeMode.system;
    }
  }

  /// Persists the user's preferred ThemeMode to local or remote storage.
  Future<void> updateThemeMode(ThemeMode theme) async {
    // Use the shared_preferences package to persist settings locally or the
    // http package to persist settings over the network.
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _prefs.setString(kPrefKeyThemeMode, theme.name);
  }
}
```

### settings_page.dart

```
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/settings';

  final SettingsController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Settings'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        // Glue the SettingsController to the theme selection DropdownButton.
        //
        // When a user selects a theme from the dropdown list, the
        // SettingsController is updated, which rebuilds the MaterialApp.
        child: DropdownButton<ThemeMode>(
          // Read the selected themeMode from the controller
          value: controller.themeMode,
          // Call the updateThemeMode method any time the user selects a theme.
          onChanged: controller.updateThemeMode,
          items: const [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: ThemeMode.system,
              child: Text('System Theme'),
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: ThemeMode.light,
              child: Text('Light Theme'),
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: ThemeMode.dark,
              child: Text('Dark Theme'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```